# Flex 3.4 - set a mx:Tree with 100% or adjustable size

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I'm trying to do this: a small panel with 3 parts, one superior with some label (header), one inferior with some buttons (footer) and one in the center with a mx:Tree and this panel can be resizable (it is a plugin with minimal dimensions).

How I can expand the size of the mx:Tree to use the rest of the visible area of this panel? I can't use % in size, there is some way?

Answer (score 0):

if your header and footer lengths are fixed, you can bind the height of the Tree to the height of the panel:

```
<s:Panel id="upPanel"
    width="220" height="100"
    minHeight="80"
    minWidth="200"
    styleName="resizePanel"
    skinClass="flex.utils.spark.resize.ResizablePanelSkin"
    title="ResizablePanelSkin">
    <mx:Tree width="{upPanel.width - 1}" height="{upPanel.height - 70}">
        <mx:XMLListCollection id="MailBox">
            <fx:XMLList>
                <AA/>
                <BB>
                    <BB1/>
                </BB>
                <CC/>
            </fx:XMLList>
        </mx:XMLListCollection>
    </mx:Tree>
    <s:controlBarContent>
        <s:Button label="ControlBar Button"/>
    </s:controlBarContent>
</s:Panel>
```

Otherwise, you'll need to re-calculate the height of the top and bottom elements and set the size of the Tree.

Here's a [demo](http://laissi.com/test/) i put online, view source is enabled.

(my demo it's based on [this](http://flexdevtips.blogspot.com/2010/06/flex-4-spark-resizable-controls.html))